# R Standard Deviation Across Rows

Tags: r, dplyr

The following code will sum columns 1 through 4 across each row in the iris data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% mutate(sumVar = rowSums(.[1:4]))
```

How do I compute the standard deviation across these same four columns, for each row in the iris data frame? I want to avoid using column names and stick with the column numbers. My column names often change each time data is queried. This does not work:

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% mutate(stDev = sd(.[1:4]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
iris %>% mutate(stDev = apply(.[(1:4)],1,sd))
```

Answer (score 2):

We could convert it to `matrix` and then do the `rowSds` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
     mutate(stDev = rowSds(as.matrix(.[1:4])))
```

Answer (score 1):

This base R should do the trick?

```
apply(iris[ ,1:4],1,sd)
```

Comment: yes - thank you! fan of easy base R solutions! loading so many weird packages at the moment.